# How to add the Custom metrics to the Sales Agreement Terms Mass update screen in Manufacturing Cloud?

Tags: lightning-experience, sales, cloud, usagemetrics, mass-action

How to add the Custom metrics(Custom fields) to the mass update screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Custom metrics will be automatically added when direct fields are added instead of Formula fields in Sales Agreement Product & Schedules.

***There is no configuration required for Adding Custom metrics.***

[image]